Using "differently from you" instead of "differently from the way you did"

(1) He explained it differently from the way you did. [my
sentence]

I assume that my sentence is correct and natural. Is it possible to replace differently from the way you did with differently from you?

(2) He explained it differently from you.


Your proposed example (2) is fine too.  It has some words elided, which should be understood.
He explained it differently from (the way) you (did).
He explained it differently from (how) you (did).

Thank you very much, Seowjooheng Singapore. Does (1) sound natural to you?

You're welcome, @Kaguyahime. Yes, (1) is fine.
